# What's the best way to add colored-sytax code snippets to a web page?

Tags: html, web, syntax-highlighting

Is there a web gadget or service or some open source solution for doing this?

Or do people just hand-code this in the HTML?

I need to add some Ruby and Python code to a web page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like [GeSHi](http://qbnz.com/highlighter/) - The generic syntax highlighter. I've had a lot of success with this in the past, GeSHi supports a TON of languages. Not only is this useful for your own syntax highlighting on your web site, but I use the source files because they contain all of the language keywords (I need them for a text-editor I'm working on with syntax highlighting). It's been a godsend.

If you specifically need just Ruby and Python highlighting, you may want to check out [NetBeans](http://netbeans.org). It has a feature to output your source code to an HTML page while keeping all of the coloured syntax.

Comment: Cool. Didn't know NetBeans had that. That's perfect. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

I think Stack Overflow uses this or something very much like it: http://code.google.com/p/syntaxhighlighter/

Answer (score 4):

I think this site uses [prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/).

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the Vim editor, its pretty simple. Just open the code in a GVIM window and save it as an HTML file (Save As.., etc).. it will do all the work for you creating an HTML file that preserves syntax highlighting.

EDIT: Its actually "Convert to HTML" on the Syntax menu. (http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Pasting_code_with_syntax_coloring_in_emails)

Answer (score 1):

[SyntaxHighlighter 2.0](http://alexgorbatchev.com/wiki/SyntaxHighlighter) was recently released here is a basic snippit to get you started:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/scripts/shCore.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/scripts/shBrushPython.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/scripts/shBrushRuby.js"></script>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/css/shCore.css"/>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/css/shThemeDefault.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        SyntaxHighlighter.config.clipboardSwf = 'path/to/scripts/clipboard.swf';
        SyntaxHighlighter.all();
    </script>
</head>


<pre class="brush: python;">
    ... code ...
</pre>

<pre class="brush: ruby;">
    ... code ...
</pre>
```